# How can we make Cedit control text highlighted even though the focus is on other dialog box?

Tags: mfc

I have one dialog box which has edit control(some text in it.) and a button(on clicking it other dialog box gets open).

I selected(highlighted) some text and clicked button, other dialog opened but edit control text was unselected.

I wanted to keep the text selected but it is not happening?
Why is is so? ans how can i do it?

Comment: This behaviour is by design. In Windows only the control that has focus should show highlighted text. Check with any standard software, you will rarely see highlighted text in more than one control at a time. If you really need to have hightlighed text in more than one control at a time you must ownerdraw your edit control, but that's another story.

Comment: If you need further assistance please comment on my answer. If the answer solves your problem: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for an EDIT control hides the selection when the control loses focus. To negate the default behavior you have to apply the [`ES_NOHIDESEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464.aspx#ES_NOHIDESEL) edit control style by calling [`CWnd::ModifyStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xhz2t1c.aspx) if you dynamically create the control or want to dynamically change the style. For a static resource you can set the *No Hide Selection* property from the resource editor.

Note, however, that when the edit control gains focus the entire contents will be selected by default. If this is not what you want you will have to subclass your edit control (both in the C++ sense as well as the Win32-API sense). You do this by deriving from `CEdit`, add an `ON_WM_GETDLGCODE` handler and mask out the `DLGC_HASSETSEL` bit:

```
class CPreservingSelectionEdit : public CEdit
{
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
public:
    afx_msg UINT OnGetDlgCode()
    {
        UINT uiCode = CEdit::OnGetDlgCode();
        uiCode &= ~DLGC_HASSETSEL;
        return uiCode;
    }
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CPreservingSelectionEdit, CEdit )
    ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

To subclass the control you will also have to attach this derived class to the control. The most straightforward way would be to add a `DDX_Control`-statement to your `DoDataExchange` implementation:

```
void CMyDlg::DoDataExchange( CDataExchange* pDX )
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange( pDX );
    DDX_Control( pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_PreservingSelectionEdit );
}
```

where `IDC_EDIT1` is the control identifier of the control you want to subclass and `m_PreservingSelectionEdit` a member variable of your dialog class of type `CPreservingSelectionEdit`.

Note also, that the behavior and visual representation are independent of each other. You can apply each individually. Consequently if you only want your edit control to retain its selection without changing the visual feedback you can implement the changes laid out in the second part of the answer alone.